# switch case in XSL

Tags: xslt, if-statement, switch-statement, conditional-statements, xsl-choose

I have a loop with the same tags to load content in ten cells but has a difference div title and background image, so I wonder is there any way to use the switch case just to put correct div title when I do for-each to load content for each cells in XSL?
something like this:





<...load the same tags content here...>

Please help me because I'm new in XSL, and thank you in anyway!!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You may use the if condition

```
<xsl:if test="expression">
  ...some output if the expression is true...
</xsl:if>
```

or choose, if there's more than one condition to check

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="expression">
    ... some output ...
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="another expression">
    ... some output ...
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    ... some output ....
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: thank you for your help very much, but I wonder can I make multies xsl:choose like multies case: in switch or just one?

Comment: Yes you can have multiple <xsl:when .... 's.  Obviously the test expression would be different in each case.

Comment: Having a look at the documentation can be a real eye-opener sometimes. ;-) http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Conditional-Processing-with-xsl:choose